# Create a trigger to update from one column to another databases column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to update from one column to another databases column, here's what I have so far. and it keeps failing. Source database is `Gamecp`, table `gamecp_gamepoints`, column is `user_points`. I want to copy to database `Billing`, table `UserStatus`, column `cash`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[gamepoints] 
ON [dbo].[gamecp_gamepoints]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cash int;

    INSERT INTO BILLING.dbo.tbl_UserStatus 
        SELECT * 
        FROM Gamecp.gamecp.gamepoints  

    VALUES (@cash,);
```

Comment: Sorry Dale VALUES Cash int

Comment: I am trying to use a trigger to copy any new data points that are added to gamecp_gamepoits column user_points Values float to another database Billing table UserStatus column cash int

Comment: Well Dale I'll tell ya I've done IT for about 25 years VMWare building servers etc etc not once when a programmer came to me with a server problem did I tell them go read the manual LOL if you don't know say nothing on this thread if I knew I would be here cause I'm not a DBA that's the reason I came here for help. stick to your manuals

Comment: I can apricate that thanks for the reply, this wouldn't be solving all my problems trust me, but then again to be steered in the right direction wouldn't be asking to much I don't think. well ok then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use triggers on SQL Server you have to understand the [`Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo-tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) because that is what you use to detect what has changed. In your case what rows are new.

Then fix your insert by adding the column to insert and selecting the value to insert and it should work.

Although I suspect you may want to insert additional columns? But that isn't specified.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[gamepoints] 
ON [dbo].[gamecp_gamepoints]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO BILLING.dbo.tbl_UserStatus (cash)
        SELECT user_points
        FROM Inserted;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Dale I in fact was able to create a trigger however I wasn't using the logic you have explained and it was a no go, I will use your suggestion thanks for your time.